# PyQt5 QPushbutton to store ariables Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, gettext

Using PyQt5 QPlaintext to store variables. Example AO = userinput?
What I have so far minus the GUI setup. I need to store it as simple variables so i can output to a DOCX. I know I have to manually user input for every QPlaintextbox available. would I use the getText(), link it to the push button to generate the variables.  Thank you for your time.

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(1340, 922)
        self.OPORD = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.OPORD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1231, 991))
        self.OPORD.setTabBarAutoHide(False)
        self.OPORD.setObjectName("OPORD")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_4)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 240, 311, 331))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("WAATS_Final.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.OPORD.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.ORDERS = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.tab)
        self.ORDERS.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1141, 1080))
        self.ORDERS.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.ORDERS.setObjectName("ORDERS")
        self.stackedWidgetPage1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.stackedWidgetPage1.setObjectName("stackedWidgetPage1")
        self.WAATS4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.stackedWidgetPage1)
        self.WAATS4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 50, 141, 20))
        self.WAATS4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.WAATS4.setObjectName("WAATS4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.stackedWidgetPage1)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 70, 271, 21))
        self.label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.stackedWidgetPage1)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 0, 181, 21))
        self.label_9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.label_9.setText("")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.num = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.stackedWidgetPage1)
        self.num.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 181, 31))
        self.num.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.num.setObjectName("num")
        self.aoi = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.stackedWidgetPage1)
        self.aoi.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 110, 431, 71))
        self.aoi.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.aoi.setObjectName("aoi")

self.COPORD = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.OPORD.setTabText(self.OPORD.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("Dialog", "Welcome"))
        self.WAATS4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TASS"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Situation"))
        self.num.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Dialog", "##-##"))
        self.aoi.setPlainText(_translate("Dialog", "?"))
    
        self.aoi.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Dialog", "AI"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Area of Interest"))
        self.AO.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Area of Operation"))
        self.ao.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Dialog", "AO"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What you want to do? What you can't do? We can't see any program logic in the provided code (since it's just the code generated from pyuic, which you should *NOT* edit, read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to know how to do that).

Comment: When my users open this program up. they type into a text box Qplaintext. Once every text box is filled in. each text box should hold a string variable in which I format to DOCX using import text.

Comment: Like if you go to the doctors office and you fill everything out on a tablet and you hit complete and autofills their forms

Comment: You don't need to "hold a variable" in those fields: when you need that data, you can access the text of a QLineEdit using `text()` and that of a QPlainTextEdit using `plainText()`. If that's not what you're asking, please be more clear, but I'm under the impression that you're asking us to do that for you. If that's the case, you're out of luck: StackOverflow is not a place where people do things for you. Show us your efforts and we'll be more than happy to help you whenever you don't understand something.

Comment: Not trying to look for a handout, just how to tackle my issue.

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I see on your code, to get string from the QLineEdit you can use this code.

```
self.num.text()
```

if you print that code, it will automatically print the inputed string of QLineEdit.
you can add a QPushButton then make a signal slot to do that as a form in commonly use.
like these:

```
self.button = QPushButton()
self.button.clicked.connect(self.getLineEdit)
def getLineEdit(self):
    lineEditText = self.num.text()
    print(lineEditText)
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept using gettext not just text.

Comment: @harlitad please edit your example: you either connect to `getLineEdit` or you make it a method (which requires adding `self` to the function argument and correcting indentation).

Comment: @RoyZacharias I strongly suggest you to study the documentation. Besides the fact that I already told you about using `text()` in the comments on your question, that is a basic property you could've found on your own just by reading the docs about [QLineEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html).

Comment: @musicamante, I don't disagree with you, but documentation regarding me getting a text variable was odd because I had 30+ Qplaintext boxes and didn't know if there was an easier way to store user inputs. When you state "which you should NOT edit" or "You don't need to "hold a variable" in those fields". This is what I requested and you attacking or "strongly suggest" does not help the learning process. harlitad pointed me in the right direction... six  lines that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Nobody attacked you. I just told you that you don't need to retain variables on your own because those widget already give you access through those `text()` and `plainText()` functions, which is exactly what this answer is saying. About the "do not edit", that's a very important point: pyuic generated files should *never* be edited (as the comment in those files already suggests), most importantly because at a certain point you might need to change your UI, which would make integration with existing code very difficult.